# Styling a specific child element by hovering a parent div

Tags: css

Although it can be done using javascript or any client side scripting,whether is it possible to hover only a specific child element while hovering the parent element in CSS?

```
<style>
 .p{//some style...}
 .p:hover{//change style of child having class c2}
</style>
<div class="p">
 <span class="c1"></span>
 <span class="c2"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to pass `.c2` after your `:hover` selector:

```
.p:hover .c2{//change style of child having class c2}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to hover only child you need to add `:hover` to child element instead of parent:

```
.p .c2:hover{//change style of child having class c2}
```

Comment: @rosemary it's CSS2 and supported in many old browsers as well

Comment: but i want to change the style of child with class c2 when mouse is over the div anywhere,but this does only when the mouse is over the child itself